# Href key error when part of loop with other items

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

When I run this code:

```
url = "https://www.researchgate.net/profile/David_Severson"
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.text
soup = bsoup(data, "lxml")

for a in soup.find_all('a', {"class": "nova-e-badge nova-e-badge--color-green nova-e-badge--display-block nova-e-badge--luminosity-high nova-e-badge--size-l nova-e-badge--theme-solid nova-e-badge--radius-m nova-v-publication-item__type"}, href=True):
    print (a['href'])
```

It returns all of the links no problem.

When I put it as part of a bit more complicated of a loop with other elements:

```
item = soup.find("div", {"class": "section section-research"})
papers = [paper for paper in item.find_all("div", {"class": "nova-o-stack__item"})]

for p in papers:

title = p.find("div", {"class": "nova-e-text nova-e-text--size-l nova-e-text--family-sans-serif nova-e-text--spacing-none nova-e-text--color-inherit nova-v-publication-item__title nova-v-publication-item__title--clamp-3"})
abstract = p.find("div", {"class": "nova-e-text nova-e-text--size-m nova-e-text--family-sans-serif nova-e-text--spacing-none nova-e-text--color-inherit nova-v-publication-item__description nova-v-publication-item__description--clamp-3"})
views = p.find("ul", {"class": "nova-e-list nova-e-list--size-m nova-e-list--type-inline nova-e-list--spacing-none nova-v-publication-item__metrics"})
date = p.find("li", {"class": "nova-e-list__item publication-item-meta-items__meta-data-item"})
authors = p.find("ul", {"class": "nova-e-list nova-e-list--size-m nova-e-list--type-inline nova-e-list--spacing-none nova-v-publication-item__person-list"})
link = p.find("a", {"class": "nova-e-badge nova-e-badge--color-green nova-e-badge--display-block nova-e-badge--luminosity-high nova-e-badge--size-l nova-e-badge--theme-solid nova-e-badge--radius-m nova-v-publication-item__type"}, href=True)

print(p['href'])

print(p.text)
```

It no longer returns the href (link) that I want, and instead gives me KeyError: Href

Why is it no longer returning the links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fetch the in from the `link`

**Ex:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = "https://www.researchgate.net/profile/David_Severson"
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
item = soup.find("div", {"class": "section section-research"})
papers = [paper for paper in item.find_all("div", {"class": "nova-o-stack__item"})]
for p in papers:
    title = p.find("div", {"class": "nova-e-text nova-e-text--size-l nova-e-text--family-sans-serif nova-e-text--spacing-none nova-e-text--color-inherit nova-v-publication-item__title nova-v-publication-item__title--clamp-3"})
    abstract = p.find("div", {"class": "nova-e-text nova-e-text--size-m nova-e-text--family-sans-serif nova-e-text--spacing-none nova-e-text--color-inherit nova-v-publication-item__description nova-v-publication-item__description--clamp-3"})
    views = p.find("ul", {"class": "nova-e-list nova-e-list--size-m nova-e-list--type-inline nova-e-list--spacing-none nova-v-publication-item__metrics"})
    date = p.find("li", {"class": "nova-e-list__item publication-item-meta-items__meta-data-item"})
    authors = p.find("ul", {"class": "nova-e-list nova-e-list--size-m nova-e-list--type-inline nova-e-list--spacing-none nova-v-publication-item__person-list"})
    link = p.find("a", {"class": "nova-e-badge nova-e-badge--color-green nova-e-badge--display-block nova-e-badge--luminosity-high nova-e-badge--size-l nova-e-badge--theme-solid nova-e-badge--radius-m nova-v-publication-item__type"},href=True)

    if link:
        print(link["href"])
```

Answer (score 0):

your `p in papers` is `div` element and not `a` element as in the previous code snippet, that is why the `href` key error. maybe you want `link['href']` assuming link is not `None`.

Comment: There is an `a` element contained in the `div` though as a child, right? For example views is a `ul` element and I am not getting a problem. I used `link[href]` and then got `Nonetype object is not subscriptable`. @ddor254

Comment: so as i said it is the `link` variable and not `p`

Comment: When I try that I get the `Nonetype object is not subscriptable` error. @ddor254

Comment: so it did not find the `a` element in that div - the main difference between the two code snippets is that the first search `a` element in the whole html page and the second one searches that inside a div. try debugging it

Comment: So it looks like the problem is that some of the p values don't have an href, so it returns the `nonetype` error for those but not for others that do have that attribute. Any thoughts on how to handle the missing so that it doesn't return the error. Thanks for your help, btw. @ddor254

Comment: just check if link is not none : 
    `if link:`

          `print link['href']`
if my answer helped you please accept it.